# Padding on a table not working

Tags: css, padding

I'm trying to give even spacing all around images I have in a table, and it's not working too well.

Look at [the page](http://dlvrall.com/). I tried margin, padding, everything I could on lots of different types of properties, but no luck. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `rowspan="2"` on your second cell... remove that and the spacing evens out.  You may also want the following CSS (tested with Firefox/firebug rewrites)

```
<style>
#Table_01,#Table_01 a {margin:0;padding:0;}
#Table_01 img {padding:1em;}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. One more thing - how can I center the #main div? All of the other divs are centered as I want them, but the #main div does not cooperate.

Comment: Drop `width`, `height` from your `<table...` declaration, and change your CSS `#main` style to use `width:997px;` instead of `width:55%` (percentages and auto-margins are the problem :))

Answer (score 1):

The table has been created in an unusual way by photoshop - resulting in dodgey markup.

1. There a differing amount of `<td>`'s in the first row compared to the others
2. There are several spacer images which have been created by photoshop; which are redundant
3. There should be no need for the use of rowspans in your `<td>`'s

To fix this issue I would suggest modifying your table so the structure looks like this:

```
<table cellpadding="5">
  <tr>
    <td><a href="http://allure.dlvrall.com"><img src="images/index_01.png" width="463" height="200" alt=""></a></td>
    <td ><a href="http://liquor.dlvrall.com"><img src="images/index_02.png" width="465" height="200" alt=""></a></td>
  </tr>
....
```

Then keep adding blocks of table rows e.g.:

```
<tr>
      <td>... </td>
      <td>...</td>
</tr>
```

with your links and images replacing the '...'. then finally close the table:

```
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying value for `cellpadding` attribute for the table.

Comment: I tried changing both cellpadding and cellspacing but the behavior is similar to doing that in the stylesheet; the cells are still staggered. It was sliced in Photoshop, maybe it's leftover formatting from that?

Comment: @Andrei Korchagin: Try specifying the max possible height that you elements are.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is all wrong. You have TDs using rowspan when its not needed and i see some spacer gifs. Fix the markup and you wont have any issues with using cellpadding